# Apple Business Manager Error not covered on support page - Account Update Not Allowed

Tags: active-directory, apple-business

We have begun the processing of syncing Apple Business Manager with our Microsoft Intune instance (all Azure Active Directory accounts) via SCIM.  In the logs, for 2 of our accounts, I am given the error "Account Update Not Allowed."

This error is not included on this page: https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/apple-business-manager/apddc1fec242/web , nor is Google bringing up any hits, so I don't know what it means or how to fix it.

Comment: Same problem here. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

For SCIM errors, you will want to open a case with Apple support to validate it’s not temporary on their end. Our business engineer is amazing and hopefully your support team is responsive as well.